# web2py: Radio Buttons not rendering on SQLFORM error

Tags: web2py

I'm using custom radiobuttons with a SQLFORM as shown below:

```
def radioboxes(field,value):
    items=[DIV(name,INPUT(_type='radio',_value=key,_name=field.name,value=value), _class='radio')
       for key,name in field.requires.options() if key]
    return items

db.define_table('table1',
    Field('name', 'string', length=16, required=True, unique=True, ),
    Field('shape', 'string', length=12, default='star', widget=radioboxes, requires=IS_IN_SET(shapes)))
```

I use this to edit the table

```
record = db.table1(session.table1_id)
form = SQLFORM(db.table1, record, fields=['name', 'shape'], showid=False, deletable=True, delete_label='Delete', col3=col3)     # edit/delete
```

This works perfectly, except when there's an error in the form - if I use a non-unique value for the name field, I get the expected error message, but the radio-buttons are not rendered correctly anymore - they show up as:

```
[<gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9F850>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9F130>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9FFD0>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9F070>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9FD10>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9F8F0>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9FE10>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9FF90>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9FE90>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9F6B0>, <gluon.html.DIV object at 0x08C9F610>]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I fixed it by enclosing the generated radio buttons in their own div:

    def radioboxes(field,value):
    items=[DIV(name,INPUT(_type='radio',_value=key,_name=field.name,value=value), _class='radio')
           for key,name in field.requires.options() if key]
    return DIV(*items)

(added the DIV in the return)

Comment: Yes, your widget should return a single HTML helper object, not a list of helper objects. Also, if you want 'name' to be unique, you should add a `requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'table1.name')`. The `unique=True` is enforced by the database, not by the form, so a non-unique name will trigger a database error, but won't give the proper form error upon form validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by enclosing the generated radio buttons in their own div:

```
def radioboxes(field,value):
items=[DIV(name,INPUT(_type='radio',_value=key,_name=field.name,value=value), _class='radio')
       for key,name in field.requires.options() if key]
return DIV(*items)
```

(added the DIV in the return)